# NHibernate Upgrade from 1.x to 3.x causes this Ex: 'Antlr.Runtime.EarlyExitException'

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I had to upgrade the latest version of hibernate for a solution I have, but the problem is I am now getting a really weird exception for certain queries.  Here is the important part of the stack trace:

NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QuerySyntaxException: Exception of type 'Antlr.Runtime.EarlyExitException' was thrown. [select new xxx.LineItemView( item.Id)  join y join z.. etc

(I just removed our names spaces and the actual query)

Would anyone have any idea why this is happening?  Like i was saying I think for anything that isnt a simple query I seem to get this error? :/

Thanks in advance

Neil

Comment: Ok.. ive made some progress, the fact that im using a select new namespace.MyObject( params....) in the hql, its causing the error.  When i remove it and just run a normal query that returns a non typed ilist it works.. 

anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't find much details on this error, and there wasnt much action on SO, but we found the solutions.  NH needs to use the old parser as the syntam "Select new MyObject(xx.x)" is redundant in 3.x

You can do this by adding this to the NHibernate configuration:

```
 <property name="query.factory_class">NHibernate.Hql.Classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory</property>
```